# Java Memory barrier on CPU level

Tags: java, memory

I am wondering about the mechanism for Memory Barrier on the CPU level, not compile level. Is it possible in Java? The `synchronized` keyword introduces a memory barrier and different to consider like happens-before, etc.
w

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: In addition to the very important XY problem that Andy mentioned, there's also the problem that "Java memory barrier" and "CPU level" don't mix: Java is explicitly designed to *shield* you from all the nitty-gritty CPU-level details. Which means you don't *need* to know them but also can't directly interact with them from Java.